# How do I represent a * when asking a question?

Tags: support

I was trying to post something here that had two (nonconsecutive) asterisks in the text.  They ended up being replaced by spaces.  How can I represent those asterisks?

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this page](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) of the help center for details on how to format your posts. Briefly, you can either enclose the asterisks in backticks: `**` (which is rendered like this: `**`), or you can break the flow of your text and use indentation or quote blocks (`>`).

I won't go into detail here since this is all explained quite well in the [relevant help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Unfortunately the news about backticks isn't on that help page.  I had looked there.

Comment: @user101815 huh, so it isn't. That one is hidden a bit deeper, true. However, if you select your text and hit the "code" button that is above the text entry field for questions and answers (the one that looks like `<$>`, it will add backtics around the selection.